# Can I find Deep Color monitors?

Tags: colors

I have been reading about [Deep Color](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth#Deep_color_.2830.2F36.2F48-bit.29) (aka high bit depth color) and I understand that I can produce it in software, but how do I know if my monitor can support it?

If it can't, are there any monitors that support Deep Color?

Where do I look? (I have already tried just searching for Deep Color monitors. They don't seem to exist on google, amazon, or newegg)

Comment: Why was this question migrated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that Deep color monitors have been around for some years

Dell Ultrasharp are some great high depth color monitors